# H-Bridge L298N motor driver

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, shields

I have 2 motors connected to a dual H-Bridge motor driver and the H-bridge connected to an arduino uno, It was working fine at first but now my motors are spinning very slow and the car bearly moves, I have changed the batteries  but still moves slow and with no power, please help

Comment: What motors? What driver? What batteries? Try to give a bit more detail.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with my motor driver. Initially I ran the code and connected the L298N with arduino and it worked fine. At that time motors were running absolutely fine. But when I ran it sometimes later then the motors are not running. However the motors are getting power but I think thy are getting very less power from the Motor Driver. I directly ran motors from Arduino +5V pin and the motors were running fine. Is there something wrong with my L298N motor driver? One more thing I checked the power for all the pins for L298N motor Driver and all pins are working fine. Somebod

Answer (score 3):

You can try to bisect the problem.

Remove the Arduino and drive the motors with wires: replace the input for the pwm signal with a +Vcc and you will get the same as if the Arduino was outputting a PWM with 100% duty cycle.

This should allow you to diagnose if there is a problem with the driver/motors.

If that shows no problem and the wheels spin as expected, then you have some issue (either sw or electrical with the Arduino).

But at least you can halve the complexity of the problem.

Comment: My motor has 2 wires and to run it through the H-bridge i use 3 wires, IN1,IN2 and ENB(PWM),so are u saying I should remove the H-bridge completely or leave the motor connected to the H-bridge just remove the wire connected to ENB and connect it to +Vcc?

Comment: (IN1,IN2) work like this: when they have different values, they make the motor rotate left or right., when they are the same value they erither let the motor free and unpowered or locked and powered. You can use wires to test the 4 combinations. the En/PWM can be set and left at high value (probably 5V in your case). So yes, I'd say you could drive manually IN1, IN2, EN. If that still shows problem, then you can consider breaking down that block.

Comment: I have EN connected to +Vcc and I have IN1 and IN2 connected to D5 and D6, one set at high and the other set at Low and nothing is happening

Comment: My point was that you do not need to connect IN1 and IN2 to the Arduino: just wire them to Vcc/GND and see if the motors move.

Comment: oh k, yeah the motor works and I have actually resolved that issue, now I need help with the ublox neo-6, I get 2812989, -2591969 and it keeps going up and down, how do i configure it to give me a fixed value, I am using TinyGPS library

Comment: This now seems like a separate question, I suggest you create a new one. You will get also more attention. I wouldn't know how  to solve this new problem you described.